# jQuery - Only Call The Hover Out Function if Cursor Isn't Entering Any Siblings

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create an effect similar to the navigation on this site: http://rogwai.com/. I'm fairly close as you can this in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YZr5b/3/).

It's working fine if you hover into one li at a time (i.e. from the bottom). If however, you slide horizontally through each list item  the 'follower' returns to the active position or slides of the end after each item that's hovered over. Instead it should follow the mouse.

Looking at the code executed on hover out this is completely understandable. What I can't get my head around is how to make it only return to the active position or slide off the end when the mouse completely leaves the menu.

Hopefully that makes sense - you should see the problem straight away from the jsFiddle.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nothing noticeable is happening in the jsFiddle you provided for me (FF 10.0.2) - what exactly am I supposed to be seeing?

Comment: Are you really using jquery 1.2.6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is add the `mouseenter` part to the `li` as you have it, but put the `mouseleave` part on the entire `ul`.  This way, the leave will only fire when you mouse out of the entire `ul`.

http://jsfiddle.net/YZr5b/6/

```
$('nav.block-system-main-menu ul li:not(.follower)').mouseenter(function() {
    followerMove($(this));
});

$('nav.block-system-main-menu ul').mouseleave(function(){
    followerMove($active);
});
```

Note, if you are really using jquery 1.2.6 (quite old), you will need to modify this a bit as `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` do not exist.

Comment: I have one other suggestion, though it's not pertinent to the question so I won't put it in my answer.  If you use `stop` as follows: `$('li.follower').stop().animate({`  you will get a smoother animation and prevent odd behavior if you move the mouse around very quickly.

Comment: Turns out to be a very simple solution as usual! I'm not actually using jQuery 1.2.6 on the project - I had been trying to work out if a previous problem was caused by the version I was running.